# Paypal not working for subscription - PayPal Powered by Braintree and Woocommerce subscription

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, braintree, woocommerce-subscriptions, braintree-sandbox

As mentioned in documentation to enable Paypal vault in braintree. I am not getting option in Braintree sandbox control panel, where to enable it. Can anybody help?

Following is mentioned in documentation:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/#section-34

***Have the Braintree vault enabled in your Braintree account for credit cards, and / or have PayPal Vault enabled in your Braintree account for PayPal transactions.***

The paypal payment method is not working in this plugin. Showing this error:

*Currently unavailable.*

Comment: The [Vault](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview) should be enabled by default for all Braintree accounts, so you can ignore that first step. I'm unsure about PayPal showing as "Currently unavailable" though. Is that happening within the subscription plugin or WooCommerce itself?

Comment: @David, The error of Paypal is shown in checkout page. This error showing for all products either subscription or simple products.

Comment: Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. I've definitely seen errors similar to this in the past, however they've always been specific to certain account types and settings that are best fielded by [our Support team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact). I recommend reaching out so that they can provide some perspective specific to your account.